# How to overwrite abstract method of a child class of a super class, from the inheriting class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I have a `class KA`, which has two *methods*, `add()` and `subtract()`, and an *abstract child* `class KAX`. `KAX` has an *abstract method*, `multiply()`. There is another `class KB` which *inherits* `KA`, and by extension has access to `KAX.multiply()`. I would like to **overwrite/define** `KAX.multiply()` from `class KB`. How to do this?

So far what I could think of is define a private method `__multiply()` under `class KB`, and then redefine under `KB.__init__()` as follows:

```py
self.KAX.multiply = self.__multiply()
```

This works. However, I am wondering if there is a better way to do what I am trying to achieve here. Thank you.

**My current code:**

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class KA():

    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 3
        self.B = 10
        self.C = self.B**self.A

    @abstractmethod
    def add(self): pass

    @abstractmethod
    def subtract(self): pass

    class KAX(ABC):

        @abstractmethod
        def multiply(self): pass


class KB(KA):

    def __init__(self, A = 3, B = 10):
        #super(KB, self).__init__()
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.KAX.multiply = self.__multiply
        self.KAX.multiply()
        self.C = self.KAX.multiplication

    def add(self):
        self.addition = self.A + self.B

    def subtract(self):
        self.subtraction = self.A - self.B

    def __multiply(self):
        self.KAX.multiplication = self.A*self.B


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kb = KB(A = 4, B = 2)
    # check values of variables: A, B, C
    print('Parameters: A, B, C')
    print(''.join(['kb.{}: {}\n'.format(vname, getattr(kb,vname)) for vname in ['A', 'B', 'C']]))
    # apply methods
    kb.add()
    kb.subtract()
    kb.KAX.multiply()
    # show results
    result_string = 'Result: \n\t addition: {}\t | subtraction: {}\t | multiplication: {}'
    print(result_string.format(kb.addition, kb.subtraction, kb.KAX.multiplication))
```

The output of this code results in:

```
    Parameters: A, B, C
    kb.A: 4
    kb.B: 2
    kb.C: 1000

    Result: 
         addition: 6     | subtraction: 2    | multiplication: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

`KAX` isn't a child class, it's just a class defined *within another class*. So, you can subclass it and override its methods:

```
class KB(KA):
    class KAX(KA.KAX):
        def multiply(self):
            print("hello!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try making a new class called KB.KAX that extends KA.KAX and then implementing your method like so:

```
class KA():
    class KAX():  
        @abstractmethod
        def multiply(self): pass

class KB(KA):
    class KAX(KA.KAX):
        def multiply(self):
            print("doing stuff")
```

Comment: Thank you @Joseph. I tried your and @ForceBru's solution. But it did not work. See, I need access to the instance of KB as well for certain attributes. For instance, if I need access to KB.B to do something, the error says that I am missing an argument `self`.

Comment: I think the issue there could be that you're not instantiating KB.KAX but you're trying to use it like an instantiated object. If you make a call like kb.KAX.multiply() (where kb is an instance of KB), you're calling the static method multiply() of KB.KAX. If you want KB.KAX.multiply() to operate on KB objects, you could have it take a KB object as a parameter instead of self.

Comment: Yes, I tried using `kb.KAX.multiply(kb)` and it works. But, what I would like to do is instantiate `kb` first, then under `kb.KAX` access the method `multiply()` and operate that on some attribute(s) of `kb`.

Comment: You would need to make KAX an instance of some object instead of a class. Like, you could define a KAX class and then give KB an instance variable kax of type KAX that could run the methods. In the KAX's __init__, you could give its parent KB object as a parameter so it knows what to run the multiply operation on